# How to compare the elements of an char array using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
char[] l = {'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Now, what i want to accomplish is to compare the first element of the array with the second one, move forward (compare second one with third, and so on) if they match, but if they don't then take the first element that doesn't match with the next one. Doing something similar like this:

```
var l = l.TakeTheFirstOne((x, y) => x != y)
```

In this case the answer should be the char `'a'` at second position.

Comment: what result do you expect from {'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'} ?

Comment: what result you expect?

Comment: 'a' ( since the char 'a' at second position doesn't match up to char 'b' at third position)

Comment: I would suggest using https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#lag or https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#lead .

Comment: What do you expect from `{'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'}`?

Comment: I still expect `'a'` as I wan the first element that doesn't match. @mjwills

Comment: What is your "real" problem then? Is there any difference for you between first `a` and second? Is this a homework or something?

Comment: @SeM maybe he wants to write a clever 1 liner on hackerrank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var answer = l.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
         .FirstOrDefault(x => (x.index != l.Length - 1) && x.item != l[x.index + 1])?.item;
```

Comment: @r796 the first part does not do what is expected. please review!

Comment: is more interesting to find the position of the character, this is the true match. if you look for the character you later need to find the last position from the beginning equals to the character found

Comment: @r796 in the second part that problem is mitigated and you can select the index as well.

Comment: @r796 check my solution below for more ideas. hope this help!

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov is not wrong but is just looking at the character value and is more helpful to get the index as well like you do in the second solution.

Comment: @Miguel, I think questioner knows better, what he want, not we

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov don't take it personal ;-) is just a comment

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov the result may be right but you are using grouping + last iteration + another last iteration, this have a decent performance because the sample list is short. I think that you are overusing some Linq structures there. In addition in the first select you can use the .Key property [instead of .Last()]

Comment: @Miguel, I am glad, that my answer is so interesting for you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the select, this version will iterate over the matching items of the collection without the count condition.

```
char[] items = {'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'};
var position = items
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((character, index) => new {character, index})
    .SkipWhile(t => t.character == items[t.index])
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.index;
```

Answer (score 0):

**If efficiency is important: use Yield return in an extension function**

Although the solution with the GroupBy / Select / Last / FirstOrDefault / Last might works, it is easy to see that the sequence is enumerated several times.

Whenever you think that LINQ is missing a function, why not extend `IEnumerable` with your desired function? See [Extension Methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
// from a sequence, takes the first one that is unequal to the previous one
// and skips all following equal ones
// example: 2 2 2 5 4 4 2 will result in: 2 5 4 2
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeFirstOne<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    TSource firstDifferentItem = source.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstDifferentItem != null)
    {   // at least one item in the sequence
        // return the first item
        yield return firstDifferentItem;

        // enumerate the other items, until you find a different one
        foreach (TSource nextItem in source.Skip(1))
        {
            // if nextItem not equal: yield return
            if (!firstDifferentItem.Equals(nextItem))
            {
                 firstDifferentItem = nextItem;
                 yield return firstDifferentItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
char[] items = ...;
IEnumerable<char> differentItems = items.TakeFirstOne();
```

### Using IEnumerator

If you look closely, you'll see that the first element of the sequence is accessed two times(once for the `FirstOrDefault` and once for the `Skip`), all other elements are accessed exactly once.

If you want to optimize this even further, you'll have to enumerate yourself and remember how far you already have enumerated:

**Version that enumerates exactly once**

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeFirstOne<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {   // there is at least one element in the section.
            TSource firstDifferentItem = enumerator.Current;
            yield return firstDifferentItem;

            // continue enumerating:
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // if Current not equal: yield return
                if (!firstDifferentItem.Equals(enumerator.Current))
                {
                     firstDifferentItem = enumerator.Current;
                     yield return firstDifferentItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Full version with KeySelector, ElementSelector and EqualityComparer

TODO: Consider to add a version that takes a KeySelector (which property to check), an IEqualityComparer (when are two Keys equal?) and ElementSelector (which properties to return if the Keys are unequal?). As an example use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548652(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
{
     // select the key from the first element
     // yield return elementSelector(sourceItem)
     // check all other elements: get the key, if equal: skip. else:
     // remember key and yield return elementSelector(sourceItem)
     // use comparer to check for equal key
     // use comparer == null, use EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default
}
```

Once you've got this one, let your other overloads call this one.

Comment: This is also enumerating the source several times, with `Any`, `First` and `foreach` + `Skip`. You would also expect a `First*` LINQ method to return a single result rather than an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you wrap the input enumerable `new [] { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c' }` with: `IEnumerable<T> Log<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) { foreach (var item in source) { Console.Write(item); yield return item; } }` before calling your code, it prints `aaaabc`

Comment: The Any will do only one MoveNext; The Skip(1) will also do one MoveNext extra. So in total your complete sequence is accessed, and your first element is accessed one more time extra. Which is much better then GroupBy (= access all), then Select (= access all in every group), Last (= access all in the group). If you think this one extra element because of Any is too much, use MoveNext. This way your sequence is accessed exactly once. I didn't use it, because a lot of people are unfamiliar with the use of `IEnumerator` / `Curent` / `MoveNext`

Comment: Yes it's better, but it's still multiple enumerations, which could be expensive (e.g. items from the database - the expensive part is usually getting up to the first item) or have side effects. The first element is enumerated 3 times (`Skip` still enumerates it, it just doesn't `yield` it). It could be refactored to only do a single enumeration by using `GetEnumerator`. The `Any` becomes `MoveNext`, `First` becomes `Current` and then you just keep using the standard `while(MoveNext){Current}` for the rest of the `foreach`.

Comment: I already said: if that is really a problem, use `Ienumerable.GetEnumerator` and `IEnumerator.MoveNext` / `IEnumerator.Current`

Comment: Your answer is entirely about performance, so why not just update your answer? As you said, some people are unfamiliar with `IEnumerator`, so it would be nice to have the complete implementation in the answer rather than leaving it to the reader to take the answer, read the comments and improve the implementation. The main thing is that people just don't expect a linq method to enumerate the source multiple times.